# Como hacer un array multidimensional?

Tags: java

Acabo de iniciar mis estudios y hasta ahora se como crear un array unidimensional, quisiera saber como hacer uno con multiple dimensiones. Gracias.

Comment: Hola Santiago. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Para hacer una buena pregunta has dee explicar lo que intentas hacer, lo que has probado, los problemas que te han surgido... Mira [ask] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: Santiago [mira esto](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html). Es un buen punto de partida para el aprendizaje. Está en inglés, pero dominar algo de inglés es esencial en programación, *todavía*.

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/)

Answer (score 1):

Agregas un corchete adicional por cada dimensión.

```
int[] unidimensional=new int[123]; // matriz líneal por ejemplo para guardar sonido
int[][] bidimensional=new int[123][123]; // cuadrada por ejemplo para guardar imágenes
int[][][] tridimensional=new int[123][123][123]; // tridimensional, por ejemplo para guardar modelos 3D
int[][][][] tetradimensional=new int[123][123][123][123]; // tetradimensional
```

Existen formas muy complejas de definir arreglos pues realmente cada corchete adicional crea un arreglo de arreglos, y puedes hacer cosas complejas como tener arreglos de distintos tamaños para cada arreglo en cada dimensión.

Por ejemplo en una inicialización explícita de un arreglo bidimensional podrás notar el uso de arreglos dentro de arreglos:

```
int[][] multi = new int[][]{
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
};
```

Este tipo de inicialización equivale a primero definir un arreglo como

```
int[][] bidimensional=new int[5][10];
```

y luego recorrerlo para llenarlo de ceros.

En cuanto a las formas complejas, puedes por ejemplo definir solo algunas de las dimensiones, por ejemplo

```
int[][] bidimensional=new int[5][];
```

lo que nos diría que tenemos un arreglo de 5 arreglos de enteros de tamaño de momento indeterminado y por lo mismo puedes poner arreglos de distintos tamaños inicializando cada uno de ellos dinámicamente.

Si tuvieras una mejor noción de para qué lo piensas usar, tal vez te podríamos recomendar la estructura de datos apropiada o la forma de crear el arreglo que necesitas.

Comment: aunque tu respuesta es valida para solucionar la pregunta, el usuario no coloco un [ejemplo minimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) tambien te inivto a leer  [como responder preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Como dice @JackNavaRow has de ser paciente antes de responder. El usuario tiene que mejorar mucho la pregunta para que sea de calidad y respondiendole estamos indierctamente aceptando este tipo de contenido. Un saludo

Comment: 20 minutos no es suficiente paciencia? este mismo tipo de preguntas se presentan en la versión en inglés ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431670/how-to-define-single-and-multidimensional-array-in-php ). Y @JackNavaRow yo creo que esta es la primera vez que alguien vota negativo por una omisión del usuario.

Comment: no digo que esperes un tiempo como 20 min antes de responder. digo que esperes el que haga falta hasta que la pregutna sea de calidad. Como si son 5 h.. aunque para entonces esa pregunta se habra cerrado porque no es valida en **este sitio**. Notese que este no es el sitio ingles, asi que no todo el funcionamiento es paralelo al otro. Un saludo

Comment: La calidad es algo subjetivo, y una pregunta que explica como inicializar arreglos desde lo más básico a lo más complejo puede ser un buen wiki de comunidad y servir de referencia a alguien en el futuro.

Comment: Se esta contribuyendo a que nuevos usuarios no tomen en cuenta lo definido en el [help], específicamente lo definido en [ask] , para mi paciencia son 24 horas, el usuario por ejemplo pudo haberse quedado dormido (como a varios de nosotros nos sucede) y no completo o formulo su pregunta correctamente. Nuestra tarea como comunidad es ayudar a los nuevos usuarios a realizar preguntas que puedan en verdad ser de ayuda a no solo el que pregunta si  no a otros desarrolladores.

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys, ya expuse la situación en el meta para recibir más valiosas opiniones https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2906/la-calidad-de-una-respuesta-depende-de-la-calidad-de-una-pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Array de una dimension de 10 celdas

```
int[] arrayUnaDimension = new int[9];
```

Array de dos dimensiones de 10 x 10 celdas

```
int[][] arrayDosDimensiones = new int[9][9];
```

Array de tres dimensiones de 10 x 10 x 10 celdas

```
int[][][] arrayDeTresDimensiones = new int[9][9][9];
```

Array de tres dimensiones de 10 x 10 x 10 x 10 celdas

```
int[][][][] arrayDeCuatroDimensiones = new int[9][9][9][9];
```

Tambien se pueden hacer arrays de String, float, boolean... Lo unico que tienes que hacer es sustituir donde pone int el String por ejemplo.

Comment: aunque tu respuesta es valida para solucionar la pregunta, el usuario no coloco un [ejemplo minimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) tambien te inivto a leer  [como responder preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Como te dice @JackNavaRow has de ser paciente antes de responder. El usuario tiene que mejorar mucho la pregunta para que sea de calidad y respondiendole estamos indierctamente aceptando este tipo de contenido. Un saludo